# What does this log mean?

Tags: android-job

I scheduled a job at 20:23 (GMT 5:30 included).

```
int jobId = DailyJob.schedule(new JobRequest.Builder(XXXXX_DAILY_JOB_TAG), 0, TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(20));
```

I am trying to schedule a daily job from midnight 00:01 am to 20:00 (8:00 pm).

I notice the following log:

```
06-27 20:23:25.693 8855-8855/com.xxxxx D/JobProxy26: Schedule one-off jobInfo success, request{id=17, tag=xxxxx_daily_job, transient=false}, start 03:36:35, end 23:36:35 (from now), reschedule count 0
```

What specifically is this log trying to tell me? (`start 03:36:35, end 23:36:35 (from now)`)?

Am I scheduling the daily job correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it.

```
start 03:36:35, end 23:36:35 (from now)
```

Starting from `06-27 20:23:25.693`(logcat schedule time) when the job was scheduled, the job will be triggered after `03:36:35` time and before `end 23:36:35` from `now(06-27 20:23:25.693)`.

in a nutshell it's the delay from now(current scheduled time).